# Python __init__() how don't override important functionality?

Tags: python, tkinter, init, super

I need to add another option in a class, a simple 'edit=False'. Whithout override completely **init**().
I found this piece of code written for kivy:

```
class TitleBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # make sure we aren't overriding any important functionality
        super(TitleBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

But when I try to edit for my purposes I receive: "TypeError: **init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"

```
class Person_Dialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, edit=False, **kwargs):
        super(Person_Dialog, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.edit = edit
```

Comment: I do not get this error in either python 2 or 3, can you show more code? how you're calling it?

Comment: Can you show us the __init__ for tkSimpleDialog.Dialog?

Comment: It seems possible to me that the super().__init__ doesn't accept **kwargs

Comment: I call it `add = Person_Dialog(root, 'Add person')` and it works fine if I omit the __init__ method! And the 1st piece of code itself works fine too.

Comment: Your last commit doesn't make any sense to me.  What do you mean "if you omit the init method"

Comment: Those are not keyword arguments, they are positional.

Comment: have you tried with `*args, **kwargs` instead of just `**kwargs`?

Comment: @bravosierra99 I mean, if I don't define init at all (this is how I'm sure that the rest of the code is ok)

Comment: @faber I could be horribly wrong, but I don't think you can pass parameters to a class that doesn't have an __init__ method...

Comment: @SteveBarnes `def __init__(self, parent, title = None):` this is the init of "tkSimpleDialog.Dialog" so one it's positional and one keyword. This is the point, how can I add another keyword argument?

Comment: yea, just checked, you have to have an __init__method defined if you want to pass any parameters.  So I"m not sure how your code is "working" if you don't implement the __init__

Comment: @bravosierra99:  It works with no `__init__` because it inherits `__init__` from the superclass.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski h yes, good point

Comment: @janbrohl with `*args, **kwargs` I have `super(Person_Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an `__init__` signature of:

```
def __init__(self, edit=False, **kwargs):
```

When you do this:

```
add = Person_Dialog(root, 'Add person')
```

Python creates an instance and assigns it to the `self` argument.  Then it assigns `root` to the `edit` argument.  Then it takes `'Add a person'` and finds no other *positional* arguments to assign it to.

To fix this add another argument to `__init__`:

```
class Person_Dialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, edit=False, **kwargs): # added parent argument
        super(Person_Dialog, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.edit = edit
```

Note that we also pass `parent` to the superclass because `tkSimpleDialog.Dialog` has this signature `__init__(self, parent, title=None)`.

Unfortunately, your code now fails with `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` because `tkSimpleDialog.Dialog` is an old style class and you can't use `super()` with old style classes.  (Python 3 does away with old style classes, so you won't have this issue there.)

So to fix this replace the call to `super()` with a direct reference to the superclass:

```
class Person_Dialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, edit=False, **kwargs):
        # referencing the superclass directly
        tkSimpleDialog.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs) 
        self.edit = edit
```

Now your code will work.